# EasyPieChart.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the easypiechart, but i don't know why it is not showing any thing...

i add the **easypiechart.js** and the below code before the `**</body>**`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.Chart').easyPieChart({
            //your configuration goes here
            size:170,
            animate: 2000,
            lineCap:'butt',
            scaleColor: false,
            barColor: '#ccc',
            lineWidth: 10
        });
    });
</script>
```

in my html i call the piechart using this code..

```
 <div class="Chart" data-percent="73"><span class="percent">73%</span></div>
```

the result look like...

73%

there is no circle show aroound 73%.

please solve with example code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you confirm that all the files are included properly,
place the script after the easypiechart.js file
if the javascript is not working then try to direct access using this [Link](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/javascripts/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js)